# Using IOCTL to get WiFi Client RSSI information

Tags: using, ioctl

I am trying to get hold of RSSI levels for WiFi clients connected to a Z8102AX router. The router uses a special image of OpenWrt. The details are:

```
[    0.000000] Booting Linux on physical CPU 0x0000000000 [0x410fd034]
[    0.000000] Linux version 5.4.213 (quds@quds-PowerEdge-R420) (gcc version 8.4.0 (OpenWrt GCC 8.4.0 unknown)) #0 SMP Tue Sep 12 07:57:31 2023
[    0.000000] Machine model: MediaTek MT7981 RFB

root@061204100004:/# ubus call system board
{
        "kernel": "5.4.213",
        "hostname": "061204100004",
        "system": "ARMv8 Processor rev 4",
        "model": "MediaTek MT7981 RFB",
        "board_name": "mediatek,mt7981-spim-snand-rfb-z8102ax",
        "release": {
                "distribution": "OpenWrt",
                "version": "21.02-SNAPSHOT",
                "revision": "23.0921_091445",
                "target": "mediatek/mt7981",
                "description": "OpenWrt 21.02-SNAPSHOT unknown"
        }
}
```

The OpenWrt image does not seem to be a stock image and the kernel does not include the nl80211 module. The WiFi extension WEXT does seem to be loaded.

But iwconfig does not provide RSSI signal levels. The level is always given as 0.

My question is. Is it worth trying to use IOCTL to get the RSSI level. Given that this is a MT9871 device and there seems to be no driver information from mediatek.
How can I progress this or am I wasting my time?

I have tried googling possible solutions and understand that the latest version of Linux uses iw. When I try iw I get 'nl80211 not found'. When I check the kernel config file the nl80211 modules are not loaded but WEXT is.

If I try iwconfig all the I get

```
rax0      IEEE 802.11ax  ESSID:"gateway-0515"
          Mode:Master  Channel:44  Access Point: FA:5E:3C:5C:72:66
          Bit Rate=286 Mb/s
          Link Quality:10  Signal level:0  Noise level:0
          Rx invalid nwid:0  invalid crypt:0  invalid misc:0
```

All the information is set to zero

Many thanks. MPC